# Converting PDO to mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pdo

Need help in converting PDO array execution to mysqli statements. This executes for an AJAX POST call for deleting a particular id from database with SWAL function.

```
 <?php
require_once 'connectivity.php';
$response = array();

if ($_POST['delete']) {


    $pid = intval($_POST['delete']);
    $query = "DELETE FROM students WHERE id=$pid";
    $stmt = mysqli_query($query,$connect);
    $stmt->execute(array(':pid'=>$pid));

    if ($stmt) {
        $response['status']  = 'success';
 $response['message'] = 'Student Deleted Successfully ...';
    } else {
        $response['status']  = 'error';
 $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete ...';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is the consecutive swal function which is to be executed once the delete button clicked.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#deleteid', function(e){

        var productId = $(this).data('id');
        SwalDelete(productId);
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});

function SwalDelete(productId){

    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "It will be deleted permanently!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,

        preConfirm: function() {
          return new Promise(function(resolve) {

             $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'delete' : productId} 
             })
             .done(function(response){
                swal('Deleted!', response.message, response.status);
                readDetails();
             })

             .fail(function(){
                swal('Oops...', 'Something went wrong with ajax !', 'error');
                window.location.reload(true);
             });
          });

        },
        allowOutsideClick: false              
    }); 

}


function readDetails(){
    window.location.reload(true);   
}
```

Comment: a) with what exactly do you need help? b) use prepared statements. currently you are open to SQL injections.

Comment: I am testing it in local so no need to fear about SQL Injection, but the thing is as i am changing all my statements to one single mySQLi Statements so i need the last line $stmt->execute(array(':pid'=>$pid)); to be in mySQLi

Comment: Have you done some research already? Please check the [mysqli manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: In the current code you should be able to just drop it as `mysqli_query()` already executes the query. Regarding the SQL injections - I *strongly* suggest to always take care of that or you will forget about it even if this goes to production.

Comment: I agree upon that thank you for your valuable time will take care of this.